# Why is the order of channels receiving causing/resolving a deadlock in Golang?

Tags: go, concurrency

I've boiled my issue down to this simple example below. I am invoking a goroutine that takes two channels and sends one message to each. Then I am attempting to receive those messages further along. However, the order of channels receiving matters. If I use the same order I sent the messages, the program runs. If I switch, it does not.

I would have expected the goroutine to run independently from retrieving the messages, allowing me to receive from whichever channel I wanted to first.

I can solve this by sending messages to a single channel per goroutine (2 goroutines).

Could someone explain why there is an order dependence here and why 2 separate goroutines resolves that dependence?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    chanA := make(chan string)
    chanB := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        chanA <- "el"
        chanB <- "el"
    }()

    // if B is received before A, fatal error
    // if A is received before B, completes
    <-chanB
    <-chanA

    fmt.Println("complete")
}
```

Comment: Because sending and receiving on channels are blocking by default. This is covered by the tour of go or any other basic tutorial for the language.

Comment: @super I am reading those tutorials, but I must be dense because I'm not seeing the connection to my example.

Comment: Your goroutine tries to send on `chanA`, but there is no receiver. So it waits. The main threads tries to read on `chanB`, but there is no sender, so it waits.

Comment: @super but there IS a receiver and sender defined. Is Golang not able to see them? Or does the message have to be received before the goroutine can continue?

Comment: Yes, that's what `blocking` means. Channels are by default a way to communicate, but also a way to synchronize. If you try to send, it will block until someone else actually receives. And vice versa.

Comment: @super thank you, I think I'm understanding now. fwiw `blocking` by itself is ambiguous as there are multiple blockable concepts here. I understood that the receiver blocked the main routine until there was a message, but it wasn't clear to me that the goroutine was blocked until the message was received. Looks like that's only the case for unbuffered channels. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to buffer your channels. A buffered channel can store so many elements before it will block.

```golang
chanA := make(chan string, 1)
chanA <- "el" // This will not block
fmt.Println("Hello World")
```

When you do `chanA <- "el"` on the **buffered** channel above, the element gets placed into the buffer and the thread does not block. If you add a second element, it will then block as there is no room in the buffer:

```
chanA := make(chan string, 1)
chanA <- "el"
chanA <- "el" // <- This will block, as the buffer is full
```

---

In your example, you have a buffer of 0. So the first write to the channel is blocked, and requires another thread to read the value to unblock.

https://go.dev/play/p/6GbsVW4d0Mg

```
    chanA := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Pop:", <-chanA) // Unblock the writer
    }()
    chanA <- "el"
```

---

#### Extra knowledge

If you do not want a thread to block, you can wrap a channel insert in a select. This will ensure if the channel is full, your application does not deadlock. One cheap way of fixing this is a larger buffer...

https://go.dev/play/p/kKR-lrCO4FX

```
    select {
    case chanA <- "el":
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("value not written: %s", value)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how goroutine works:

> a goroutine will be blocked read/write on a channel unless if find another goroutine which write/read from the same channel.

Pay attention to **read/write** and **write/read** in the above blocked quote.

In your case, your anon goroutine(which you kicked off with `go`) waits to write on `channelA` until it finds a goroutine which reads from `channelA`.
The main goroutine waits to read from channelB unless it finds a goroutine that reads from it.

You can think it this way, any line written after read/write to channel won't be considered unless go finds another routine which write/read from the same channel.

So, if you change either read or write order you will not have deadlock or as you said another goroutine will do the job too.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

A write to or read from an unbuffered channel will block until there is a goroutine to write to or read from that channel. When the goroutine writes to `a`, it will block until the main goroutine can read from `a`, but main goroutine is also blocked waiting to read from `b`, hence deadlock.

Comment: Thank you. It hadn't occurred to me that the read needed to happen before the goroutine could continue. I assumed channels were like Erlang Actor mailboxes, but clearly not.